# Доступ к компонентам другой формы

Tags: c#, файлы

Всем привет. Не могу получить путь к файлу из OpenFileDlg. Что не так, я не могу понять.

Вариант 1:

```
MainForm MainForm = new MainForm();
PeReader PE = new PeReader(MainForm.OpenFileDlg.FileName);
```

Возвращает почему-то пустую строку, но в MainForm я уже выбрал файл.

Вариант 2:

```
        public string Path()
        {
          return this.OpenFileDlg.FileName;
        }
```

Все равно пустая строка, в чем дело не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передать в текущее окно ссылку на MainForm, например в конструкторе, а потом уже оперировать полученной ссылкой для FileName. Но это плохое решение, указывающее на ошибки в проектировании, проще было бы передавать в конструкторе FileName например...

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я сглупил :)

Answer (score 5):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к `OpenFileDlg` у только что созданной формы. Вам нужно обратиться к `OpenFileDlg` полю того объекта формы, который запущен в данный момент.

PS: Мне кажется, что на лицо архитектурный просчёт. Во-первых, показывать Диалог наружу - это плохо, а во-вторых, если вам не доступно что-то, то значит, вам здесь этим пользоваться и не надо. То есть код надо перенести внутрь формы.